How to synchronously Fire URI stored in an array
one.tsx
function fnOne() {
    var urlMap = new Map();
    urlMap.put ("1", 
        ["https://thetestrequest.com/comments/1", 
        "https://thetestrequest.com/comments/2", ... 100 length])   
    urlMap.put ("2", 
        ["https://thetestrequest.com/comments/4", 
        "https://thetestrequest.com/comments/5", ... 15 length"])
        
    urlMap.forEach((key: any, value: any) => {
        console.log(key + " Loop");
        const commentsXML : any = fnTwo (value);
        commentsXML.then((ResponseArray: any) => {
            console.log(key + " ResponseArray");
            console.log(ResponseArray);
        });
    });
}

function fnTwo (value: any) {
    console.log ("Inside fnTwo");
    
    var d1 = fetch (value)
            .then (response => response.text())
            .then (data => {
                console.log ("Return response.text: " + new Date() + data);
                return data;
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error("ERROR in fetch " + error));
    return d1;  
}


Expected console output when GET for urlMap happens synchronously with 2 iterations:

1 Loop
Inside fnTwo
GET for 100 elements urlMap[0]
Return response.text: 12:00:02 IST xml response for 100 elements
1 ResponseArray
XML response for 100 elements
2 Loop
Inside fnTwo
GET for 15 elements urlMap[1]
Return response.text: 12:00:04 IST xml response for 15 elements
2 ResponseArray
XML response for 15 elements

Actual output in Console is:

1 Loop
Inside fnTwo
2 Loop
Inside fnTwo
GET for 100 elements urlMap[0] (response date is 12:00:02). 3000 ms response time.
GET for 15 elements urlMap[1] (response date is 12:00:01). 700 ms response time.
Return response.text: 12:00:02 IST xml response for 100 elements
1 ResponseArray
XML response for 100 elements
Return response.text: 12:00:04 IST xml response for 15 elements
2 ResponseArray
XML response for 15 elements

Note that response timestamp of for the 15 elements is earlier than that of 100 elements. Hence query is not fired synchronously.
How to send the request synchronously. that is, after the response is received for urlMap[0], request for urlMap[0] will be sent.

Your issue is happening because forEach is not designed to wait for any async calls made in its loop. So it is fetching the first element then continue its work then pass to the second loop without checking if the first fetch call is finished.
In your case you want to use a for of loop.
You should also probably convert your .then into async/await which make it more readable and easier to manage async calls.
function async fnOne() { // make the function async
    for (const [key, value] of urlMap) {
       console.log(key + " Loop");
       const commentsXML = await fnTwo(value); // await for the fetch to finish
       console.log(key + " ResponseArray");
       console.log(ResponseArray);
    }
}

Related issue:
Using async/await with a forEach loop
